# Error while executing async get of Outlook item property

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

Why am I getting `Could not complete the operation due to error 80043200` sometimes while getting Outlook item property (for example, Subject) in email Compose mode?

Call stack:

```
Error
   at n.prototype.execute (appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:11:86635)
   at u.DDA.OutlookAppOm.prototype.callOutlookDispatcher (appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:11:150300)
   at u.DDA.OutlookAppOm.prototype.invokeHostMethod (appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:11:150169)
   at u.DDA.OutlookAppOm.prototype._standardInvokeHostMethod$i$0 (appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:11:148443)
   at r.ComposeSubject.prototype.getAsync (appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/outlook-win32-16.02.js:11:190544)
```

We use following code for getting a field from an Outlook item:

```
sfMailApp.OfficeManager.prototype._reloadField = function (name, defaultValue) {
var deferred = $.Deferred();
defaultValue = defaultValue || '';

var item = this.getItem();

if (item.isFake) {
    deferred.resolve('');
    return deferred.promise();
}

var field = item[name];
if (field && this._isComposeMode && field.getAsync) {
    var _this = this;
    try {
        field.getAsync(function (result) {
            if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                _this[name] = _this._processOfficeData(result.value) || defaultValue;
                deferred.resolve(_this[name]);
            }
            else {
                _this._onError(result);
                deferred.reject();
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        deferred.reject();
    }
} else {
    this[name] = this._processOfficeData(field) || defaultValue;
    deferred.resolve(this[name]);
}

return deferred.promise();}
```

Code for getItem function:

```
sfMailApp.OfficeManager.prototype.getItem = function () {
var item = Office && Office.context && Office.context.mailbox && Office.context.mailbox.item ? Office.context.mailbox.item : null;

if (!item) {
    item = {
        isFake: true
    }
}

return item;}
```

One more error we're getting sometimes while trying to get user identity token:

```
{"name":"AccessRestricted","message":"Internal protocol error: -2147467259'.","code":9017 }
```

How should we handle that?

Comment: Have you initialized your Office.JS?

Comment: @MaviDomates Yes, this error occurs when Office JS is initialized.

Comment: Could you add the code you're using to make this call? Also the Outlook version(s) you're seeing this  error on.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Outlook version is 16.0.8326.2073, added code to the question above.

Comment: @SviatoslavLobach Thanks for code sample and the Outlook version number. Are you calling `this.getItem()` in `Office.initialize` ?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Literally no, we just resolve global deferred in `Office.initialize` to kick everything off. But when this deferred is resolved, `getitem` is called (we're fetching Office JS API Entities from it). Since lots of Office JS API methods are mutually connected and not stable sometimes (like `Office.context.mailbox` properties cannot be used when Outlook item doesn't exist), should we apply different behavior? It's rather strange that `getItem` should not be called after `Office.initialize` callback...

Comment: For the user identity token AccessRestricted error, are you seeing that error from a different version of Outlook 2016? In some versions of an MSI installation of Outlook 2016, there is a known issue where getUserIdenittyTokenAsync returns an error when the user account is on an Exchange 2013 server. The fix for that issue is contained in [this update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4011091/descriptionofthesecurityupdateforoutlook2016september12-2017).

Comment: To clarify about Office.initialize, it's okay to call Office JS APIs anytime within or after Office.initialize is called, but calls before then can fail. APIs like item.subject.getAsync() shouldn't fail randomly because Outlook doesn't make any server calls to get that info. Are these calls failing on particular items, or are the failures completely random? In Office.initialize, if you make a call to Office.context.mailbox.item.subject.getAsync(), does that call ever fail? In the sample it's not clear exactly when getAsync is called, so it's possible that code sometimes runs out-of-order.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT We create `sfMailApp.OfficeManager` object after `Office.initialize` is called, so these methods cannot be called when Office is not initialized. I think failures are completely random but maybe could happen in email compose mode in most cases.

Comment: We are not able to repro this on our end. Can you try using the subject API directly in Office.Initialize and see if it fails then too? Keeping it simple will help narrow down the issue for us.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT we're still gettings lots of errors "message":"An internal error has occurred.","code":9029

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT we're still seeing the error 'Could not complete the operation due to error 80043200.' while getting getTypeAsync in compose mode of email on Outlook 16.0.8528.2139